# Retorno de success do AJAX incorreto

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou usando Jquery AJAX na minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC e estou tendo um problema um tanto estranho. Ao realizar uma requisição AJAX, ao invés de ser retonado o conteúdo que quero carregar (uma nova página ".cshtml") é retornado o mesmo conteúdo da página atual. Procurei no console por algum erro, e debuguei usando o dev tools, porém ainda não entendi o que tem de errado.

**Botão em HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary-outline button-custom" id="NovoCodigo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color:#808080;">
    </span>
    <h4 style="display:inline; color:#808080;">Novo código</h4>
</button>
```

**Jquery onClick:**

```
$('#NovoCodigo').on('click', function () {
    var get_url = this.id;
    get_url = 'codigosCaixa/' + get_url + '.cshtml';
    $.ajax({
        url: get_url,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content-load').html(data);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loader').css({display: "table"});
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loader').css({display: "none"});
            }
        });
```

**Estrutura de pastas**

[image: Estrutura de pastas]


**Página exibida**
PS: o destaque em amarelo é o botão pressionado que chama o AJAX. Repare que o mesmo conteúdo da página está rendo renderizado onde deveria aparecer a view "codigosCaixa/NovoCodigo.html"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT:**

Código da View NovoCodigo.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h4 style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:20px;">Cadastrar código</h4>
<form action="@Url.Action("Create","CodigosCaixa")" id="form-manual" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    //Campos do form
           .
           .
           .
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Você não deve carregar seu cshtml dessa forma, o correto seria fazer a requisição à sua controller e action.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo dessa forma não funciona ou você quis dizer que o ideal seria usar o controller?

Comment: coloca na pergunta o conteúdo da sua view NovoCodigo

Comment: Então, você precisa criar uma action em sua controller para rederizar essa view e o seu get deverá ser pra lá, não dá para requisitar direto a view dessa forma, ainda mais que ela depende de recursos do servidor. E essa partial view não deveria estar nesse subderetório de Home, o ideal seria estar na raiz ou ainda na Shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser manter na HomeController e que a view esteja

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult NovoCodigo() {

        //Adicionar a lógica necessária para rederizar sua View            

        return View("~/Views/Home/codigosCaixa/NovoCodigo.cshtml"); 
        //Adicionar uma model caso seja necessáiro.
    }
```

E o request você faz para:

```
$('#NovoCodigo').on('click', function () {
var get_url = this.id;
get_url = '/Home/NovoCodigo';
$.ajax({
    url: get_url,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#content-load').html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loader').css({display: "table"});
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loader').css({display: "none"});
        }
    });
```